# Can the CSS Grid Allignment be controlled by a child React components?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a react project structured in the typical dashboard layout in CSS Grid. The primary work area, where React components are constantly being loaded/unloaded, is just a single Grid Cell. My problem is that depending on the work component, I may want to align it `center` or top center (I believe this is the `start` alignment). I try to set the `align-self` value i want in the work components `div` (`Comp1`) but it does not have any effect. It only seems to work if the `div` that is mapped to the cell grid (`Container-work` is altered.

- Can and should `Comp1` control its Cell Grid alignment?
- Is there a better way to pass this control to components using React? (IE: `Container` is the parent component and `Comp1` is the child component, how do I write `Container` and `Comp1` to allow this behavior)

```css
.Container-Top {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: 200px minmax(200px, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.Container-Logo {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.Container-SideNav {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.Container-TopNav {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background-color: gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.Container-Work {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.Comp1 {
  align-self: end;
  /*does nothing */
}
```

```html
<div class="Container-Top">
  <div class="Container-SideNav">
    <ul>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="Container-TopNav">
    <ul>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="Container-Logo">
    <h1>
      logo
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="Container-Work">
    <!-- React is going to add elements here 
        I may want them aligned in different ways-->
    <div class="Comp1">
      <h3>
        How can I change the alignment of Comp1?
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update #1

The React Code for `Container component looks something like this:

```
function Container() {
  return (
    <div className="Container-Top">
        <img src={logo} className="Cotnainer-Logo" alt="logo" />
        <Router>
        <div className="Container-SideNav">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/comp1">Comp1</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
         
        </div>
        <div className="Container-Work">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/comp1/:serialnum">
              <Comp1 />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          </div>
          </Router>   
  </div>
  );
}
```

### Update #2

I also use `grid` in `Comp1` to continue the grid layout. Ideally I can only use `grid` so I can just focus on learning it, but if I need to use flex, please include a way to make the nested-grid layout work.

### Update #3

The root issue seems to be that only direct children can be grid items:

> When you add display: grid to a grid container, only the direct children become grid items and can then be placed on the grid that you have created. The children of these items display in normal flow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid#introduction_to_subgrid

Comment: How is the content exactly going to affect the parent? Based on a event in the children, number of items?

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz I don't know if I need to effect the parent, I just know that I would like to change the Alignment of the Cell Grid the child is in.

Comment: Change Container-Work to be a flex container. Then you can put `align-self: flex-end;` on Comp1.

Comment: @rubenpoppe I will update the question, but I use `grid` in `Comp1` as well. I could put a containing `div` around it, but is there anyway to just keep using `grid`?

Comment: You could change Container-Work to be a grid. With the provided example the text jumps to the bottom of the black container when I add `display: grid;`.

Comment: I tried the same thing without any result. I changed `.Comp1 {
  display: grid;
  align-self: start;
}`: https://jsfiddle.net/nuz1xfv8/.

Comment: The missing info I'll say is the criteria to determine when it should be one type of alignment vs the other. What I would do would be to create an independent class for both alignments and toggle it based on the criteria you need, maybe even make it as an inline style: ```<div className="Container-Work" style={{ alignItems: someCriteria ? "start" : "center" }}>Content</div>```

Comment: If you don't use CSS in JSS, maybe you could prepare different CSS classes (ahead) and render them conditionally based on state. You can then pass a function to change this state to child components. I'm thinking something like this: `<div className={hasChanged?"class1":"class2"}/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say in the update #3, the problem is that the child of the grid is not Comp1.
The very best solution for your problem would be subgrid, but it is not supported by Chrome (and nobody knows when it will be).
The best alternative that you have right now is to use

```
.Container-Work {
    display: contents;
}
```

This makes the element "disapear", so now Comp1 is already a child of the grid container.
The drawback is that styles set to container-work won't show, because it is not displayed (but you can go around this limitation)

```css
.Container-Top {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: 200px minmax(200px, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.Container-Logo {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.Container-SideNav {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.Container-TopNav {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background-color: gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.Container-Work {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  display: contents;
}

.Comp1 {
  align-self: end;
  /*does nothing */
}
```

```html
<div class="Container-Top">
  <div class="Container-SideNav">
    <ul>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="Container-TopNav">
    <ul>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
      <l1>Work</l1>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="Container-Logo">
    <h1>
      logo
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="Container-Work">
    <!-- React is going to add elements here 
        I may want them aligned in different ways-->
    <div class="Comp1">
      <h3>
        How can I change the alignment of Comp1?
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have edited the explanation about the styles on container-work, I think it was confusing

Comment: Just found a deeper dive into @vals 's answer: https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/